# Unspoofing phone calls

Tags: twilio, sip

So I get spoofed calls and they're annoying; however from a little reading it seems like all the spoofing is only done in the Caller ID field, but that there are additionally 2-3 ANI fields that generally are used for carrier billing that are much more difficult to spoof. I also have both legitimate friends and spam calls that use blocked numbers, and again it seems it's just Caller ID being left blank and ANI still being submitted. (please correct if this assumption is wrong/there's a better value to use instead)

My end goal is to set up a "public" number that I give out to people, and that "public" number would read the ANI data, "fix" the caller ID, then forward the call to my actual number/send me a text/notification with the real number. My understanding is this is possible if I internally forwarded the call to an 800 number I own first (then forward the number back to a non-800 number to avoid charges) but I haven't seen this mentioned in any Twilio/Bandwidth.com/etc APIs - they mention a 'from' field but not how that field is determined. I've seen products that do this like Trapcall so I know it's possible somehow, but would prefer not to forward all my calls to a number I don't control.

How do I do this? If I forward a call with a fake/blocked caller ID to an 800 number on Twilio/Bandwidth will the `from` number of that forwarded call be automatically corrected/unblocked? (And would I be able to compare the `from` of the original call to the `from` of the 800 call, where a mismatch would mean a spoofed number?) Or is there some specific way the 800 number has to be setup for this/the 800 numbers off of Twilio don't work at all/etc?

I also read that ANI is not very reliable on VOIP calls, and VOIP calls are more or less anonymous. Is there any way to find out whether an incoming call is being made from a VOIP service or from an actual landline/mobile? I know there's the Caller ID lookup, but if we assume that data is unreliable can we find out just from data made available during the call itself?

Comment: from what i remember, there's not a way to read it unless you own an 800 number.  And more relevantly to what you want to do, ALL of the spam calls are voip.  Anyway, it seems like you would have much better ease of implementation with a switchboard.  Give your friends a specific number to use.

Comment: @JohnLord Do you know if it's only 800 numbers or all toll free? I tried an 833 number on Twilio and it didn't work.

Comment: the original article i read is online.  It's available here:  https://lira.epac.to/DOCS-TECH/Hacking/The%20Best%20of%202600%20-%20A%20Hacker%20Odyssey.pdf pg 664

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it does work from toll free #'s, it's just twilio specifically didn't work with it. worked with other providers.